# UV4L (RPi) - Custom web page to have same functionality as "Two-way Audio/Video"

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, uv4l

I need to create a custom web page on a Raspberry Pi to have the same functionality as the first option of the UV4L home page "http://{RPi IP Address}:8080/stream/webrtc"
How can I make a call (Video and Audio) to RPI from the web page using javascript?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by making a call, but sounds like you just want to set your config file to use the path of your custom page. I've used the [uv4l face detection example](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/custom-webapp-with-face-detection/) as a reference before.

In essence, you want to change the server options on your uv4l-raspicam.conf (or uv4l-uvc.conf depending on which driver you were using) file to use the path of your files:

```
server-option = --enable-www-server=yes
server-option = --www-root-path=/path/to/your/custom/page
server-option = --www-index-file=index.html
server-option = --www-port=80  # you can view your page by putting on your browser http://{RPi IP Address}:80
server-option = --www-webrtc-signaling-path=/webrtc
```

and then restart the service using `sudo service uv4l_raspicam restart`

Note: I believe you would have to have `uv4l-raspicam-extras` installed to be able to restart the server using `sudo service uv4l_raspicam restart`.